# I'm making a simple Login service to practice, how do I pass my list with users to my create user method

Tags: c#, list, authentication, methods

I got a tree working where I verify if the person exists in my list of users. And when the user doesn't exist I want to pass this to a seperate method that walks you through account creation and at the end adds you to the list. However I can't manage to pass my user list to the other method. What am I doing wrong. Keep in mind I'm quite new to this. I'll add the code at the end.

```
//this is from my main tree where I have users login, and this is where if you don't have an account you would make it


else { CreateUser(List < Users > user); }


public void CreateUser(List<Users> user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the username you want to use: ");
            string inputUser = Console.ReadLine();
            Users checkUser = user.Find(x => x.username == inputUser);
            if(checkUser == null)
            {
                string s1 = inputUser;
                Console.WriteLine("That username is available. Enter your password.");
                string inputPass = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter password again to verify");
                string passCheck = Console.ReadLine();
                if(inputPass == passCheck)
                {
                    user.Add(new Users { username = inputUser, password = inputPass });

                }
            }
```

Comment: `else { CreateUser(List < Users > user); }` is not valid C#. You don't specify the type when passing an argument into a method.

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your syntax with type:

```
else { CreateUser(List < Users > user); }
```

You should pass just a `user` parameter:

```
else { CreateUser(user); }
```

Comment: You're presuming that `user` is of type `List<User>`. It might be, but that'd be an awful name for a variable that represents a list of users.

Comment: @mason yep, 100% agree with you :D